# If a system is used for reference, should it be tagged with that system's tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

If you ask a question about how to simulate a condition from system X into system Y, should it be tagged with [x] and [y]?

My personal opinion (and some disagree) is that if you're referencing another system both tags belong, as if you're filtering based on tags, you'll see it with either system, and both can contribute.

I ran into a similar situation in a [couple](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9878/where-can-i-find-a-foldable-character-sheet-for-the-dresden-files) of [questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9897/how-does-adding-aspect-scope-in-dresden-files-change-the-feel-of-the-game), and [just saw a question that has this same issue](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/26162/how-can-i-contribute-to-the-game-and-have-fun-after-my-pc-dies/), so wanted to know what the general consensus was.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe.

If you want to get any mention of a game, we do have a site search functionality.  Tags are meant to be more of a first class "this is ABOUT this" designator.  So "compare me Pathfinder and D&D 3.5" - fine.  "I like games like Paranoia and Toon, so how would I do a humor game in Pathfinder" - not really. The examples you cite are marginal - to the degree that they're really about porting mechanic X from game Y to game Z, I'd tag with Y and Z.  To the extent to which they're just referring to "I know game Y" or whatever, I wouldn't.

Comment: That's basically the rationale I used for tagging my question with [tag:fiasco] as well as [tag:fate], but I wasn't sure whether it was the right thing.

Comment: This was about how my thought process went when I reviewed the tags on those questions. The character sheet one is *really* borderline, but not wanting to bump a question just to edit a borderline tag tips the decision toward leaving it alone.

Comment: One sufficient condition might be: if an expert in X can help answer the question, then tag it with X.  One use for tags it to keep an eye on the subset of questions you think you could help with.  (Don't know if anyone does that here, but it's clearly useful on larger sites like SO.)

Answer (score 0):

IMO, sometimes yes. It depends on the question.

Reason is, Question title have a limited length. Also longer titles are hard to read and discourage people to read it at all. Also a title (according to only the title itself) may refer to many different systems/campaigns etc. A question about spell casting might be a too broad category, and title might not be able to define the whote idea by itself alone. In this point, tags are very helpful.

In a page with 50 questions (some of which are highlighted) is quite crowded, long titles discourage me to read the question if it is too long. So, I prefer to check the tags first before I examine the question title. Reading broad-topiced question titles before the tags may lead me re-read the title again after I examine the tags to evaluate the question more accurately before I decided to click it and start reading the question itself.

So in most cases, tags are as important as the title for leading the reader.

If question is a comparison/simulation question (as it read from the title of the question), then people will check the tags to see if they are interested. If I do not know both of the related systems, then I would not consider reading the question. If I know or have any idea about one (or two) of them, then I decide to read it.